# ASP.NET Timeout Issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, session-timeout

I'm working on a legacy system that has the following timeout values in web.config.

```
<sessionState timeout="120" />
...
<forms name="login" timeout="240" />
```

I also have the following implemented to prevent Null session variable issues. Here's the generic version:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Session("DocNum") = ""
    Else
        If Session("DocNum") Is Nothing Then
            Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx?e=SessionExpired")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

It appears that the session variable is being cleared well under 120 min setting even though many users are on the system. This seems to be happening regularly.

I've read that the application pool could be causing this but how so? What other configurations and time-out values might be causing this issue?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is your session state set to InProc? If so, an app pool reset would cause this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your session state is set to InProc, the recycle settings for the application pool could be resetting the App Pool which clears session. "InProc" means that session is stored in memory, and as a result, any application pool resets would lose what is stored in session. You can check the system event log of the web server to see if there are any events for the application pool recycling due to a regular, recycling schedule or an error.

Comment: The default App Pool idle timeout is 20 minutes.  If you want session to last longer than that, you MUST increase this value.  http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools

Comment: @pseudocoder, the idle timeout will kill the session even if the application is being used?

Comment: if you are using "InProc", yes.

Comment: No, but the behavior the idle timeout on the session is unpredictable if the application pool idle timeout isn't set equal to or greater than its value.  Recycling settings might have a more direct relation to your problem, as noted in this answer.  Check your event log for app pool messages.